# setcookie + strtotime('tomorrow') give wrong date

Tags: php, strtotime, setcookie

Today 05/18/2011
If i do

```
echo date("H:i m/d/Y", strtotime("tomorrow"));
```

i get 00:00 05/19/2011 as it should be but if i use the same function in setcookie like:

```
setcookie("wls_yesterday_review", 'completed', strtotime('tomorrow'),'/','myhost.com');
```

My cookie will expire on 05/18/2011 at 09:00PM

Im not sure what im doing wrong but i tested different ways and different times and i always get the same result

i want to expire the cookie at 00:00 of the following day. If today is 05/18 10:00am i want it to expire on 05/19 00:00

Thanks guys

Comment: The timestamp is in UTC. How are you checking the cookie expire time? Is your local timezone UTC-3?

Comment: I checked it with a plugin for chrome or firefox cant remember now. Yes im utc -3. I ended using javascript for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime() function returns a timestamp on success, but you need a numerical value, maybe an integer, in setcookie() function. You should calculate the seconds to the end of today and add it to `time()+3600*24`

```
(time()+3600*24)+(mktime(24,0,0)-time());
```

where `mktime(24,0,0)-time()` is the number of seconds to the end of the day.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, (time()+3600*24)+(mktime(24,0,0)-time()));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand your function but im still getting the expire day :Thursday, May 19, 2011 9:00:11 PM

Answer (score 3):

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600*24);  /* expire in 1 day */
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: This doesn't explain the difference in values noted in the question.

Comment: I know that but i want to expire the cookie at 00:00 of the following day. If today is 05/18 10:00am i want it to expire on 05/19 00:00